# Fundamental group of infinitely many glued copies of a space

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, free-product

Let $C=\{p\in \mathbb{R^3}: \left\|p\right\|_{\infty}\le 1\}$ be a cube in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let $X$ be a compact, path-connected topological space  in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $X\subset C$, $\{z=1\}\cap X=(0, 0, 1)$ and $\{z=-1\}\cap X=(0, 0, -1)$.

Let $Y:=\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} \{X+(0, 0, n)\}$.

For example if $X=S^2$, $Y$ is illustrated in the following picture [image]

If $\pi_1(X)=0$, it is easy to show that $\pi_1(Y)=0$.

Now suppose $\pi_1(X)\neq 0$, what can we say about $\pi_1(Y)$ ? I know this is a vague question: I'm particularly interested to know if it is true that $\pi_1(X)$ is not finitely generated, and to "compute" $\pi_1(Y)$ in the case $X\sim S^1\times S^1$.

*My attempt to study $\pi_1(Y)$.* Let the group $\mathbb{Z}$ act on $Y$ by traslation. The projection $p: Y\to Y/\mathbb{Z}$ is a covering map. We know that $p_*$ is injective, so $\pi_1(Y)\hookrightarrow \pi_1(Y/\mathbb{Z})$. Maybe, studying $\pi_1(Y/\mathbb{Z})$ we can have some information on $\pi_1(Y)$.

Comment: Do you know [van Kampen's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/vanKampensTheorem.html)?

Comment: With some reasonable niceness condition on a neighborhood of the two special points in $X$, the fundamental group is the free product of countably many copies of the fundamental group of $X$ by Seifert-van Kampen. I think this will never be finitely generated if it's nontrivial.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I can show what you have written if the number of copies of $X$ is finite (by induction). But in this case how do you use van Kampen?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: That's correct, because any of your finitely many words will be written in finitely many letters, each lying in one of the copies of the group. So there's some copy you cannot generate any terms from.

Comment: @user72870 The idea is as follows. Call the chain of $n$ successive wedges $X_n$. Then $X_n \hookrightarrow X_{n+2}$ (adding an $X$ on each side) induces a map $\pi^{* n} \hookrightarrow \pi^{*(n+2)}$ between the fundamental groups of these spaces. Now take a limit of these induced maps and show that what you get as a result is the fundamental group of your "$X_\infty$". As Qiaochu says you need some condition or another on the neighborhoods of the points you're wedging at. I think Hatcher writes the details down somewhere in his algebraic topology book.